# Get latest of non-completed streams

Tags: rxjs

I have a function that's invoked by third-party code and passed an observable. I don't have control over when or how often the function is called. How can I create a new stream containing the latest item from every non-completed source?

`combineLatest` seems useful but (1) it includes the result of completed sources and (2) you need all of the sources at creation time.

Do I need to write a custom operator?

Apologies for any noobishness!

Comment: Could you give an example of what the 3rd party API looks like?

Comment: The third party code passes observables into my system by calling a function that I control. (So it's just a simple callback of the form (`Observable => void`). The question is just how I define this function. (It will have to manipulate state to produce the new stream I described above.)